How to mock static interface in xunit c#
I have performanceLogger class where I need to set IMyTelemetryClient. we are mocking the IMyTelemetryClient in the test even though it's value is null and throwing invalidoperation exception. below is the class and xunit.
public class PerformanceLogger : IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This has to be set before using this class
    /// </summary>
    public static IMyTelemetryClient? MyTelemetryClient { get; set; }

public void Dispose()
{   
    if (MyTelemetryClient != null)
    {
        
        MyTelemetryClient.AddEvent("N/A", "someTest");
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("MyTelemetryClient is not set");
    }
}
}

//My Xunit Class

public class PerformanceLoggerTests
{
    private readonly Mock<IMyTelemetryClient>? myClient;
    public PerformanceLoggerTests()
    {
        myClient = new Mock<IMyTelemetryClient>();
    }

[Fact]
public async Task Test_PerformanceLogger()
{
myClient?.Setup(x => x.AddEvent(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, string>>()));
var service = new PerformanceLogger();

//Act
service.Dispose();

}
}


If MyTelemetryClient is static, how do you set its value normally without unit testing? Can you use Dependency Injection instead?

PerformanceLogger.MyTelemetryClient = myClient.Object?

Your code uses MyTelemetryClient and CustomTelemetryClient. And AddEvent looks weird is it now a string or a Dictionary as second parameter?

And from the design guidelines for Dispose "A IDisposable.Dispose method should not throw an exception."

@Ralf My bad there was typo. CustomTelemetryClient is actualy myTelemetryClient. I just corrected it.
